# Why can a top-level val in a method body shadow a method argument in Scala?

Tags: scala, namespaces

I just discovered a bug which was introduced by automatically renaming a method argument in IntelliJ IDEA. The result was that the argument was shadowed inside the method body by a local val of the same name, like so:

```
def foo(arg: Int): Int = {
  val arg = 1
  arg
}

assert(foo(2)) // fail
```

(To make things worse, the compiler didn't get suspicious because of the type-unsafe `==` that I used to compare the value).

Is there any possible **reason why Scala would allow to shadow a method argument by a value in the top-level of the method body?**

**Edit:** And is there a compiler option that I can use to avoid these things to happen?

Comment: My guess is that this is allowed for "convenience" for people coming from Java where method arguments could be reassigned.

Comment: But you can't do `val arg = arg + 1`, so I don't see any convenience here...

Comment: Scala allows shadowing in general; it doesn't really pick and choose particular situations where shadowing is and isn't allowed. At least, I can't think of any cases where it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the function argument is considered to be from a higher level scope.

Certainly somewhat counter intuitive. Though, if you write it a little different it might make a little sense:

```
def foo = { (arg: Int) =>
  val arg = 1

  arg
}
```